# Faked accent in interview

Tags: interviewing, fraud

About a year ago, I got invited for an interview for, what I saw at the time as my dream position. I don't know what possessed me to do it -- maybe it was nerves or I just didn't think I'd get the job (it was way out of my league) -- but for some reason, I conducted the interview in an Australian accent. I'm not Australian. And I got the job.

I didn't know what to do when I started. I thought it would be weird to greet my new bosses and colleagues with a different accent, so I decided to maintain it. It's been almost a year now and I'm not sure I can keep it up much longer. For a start, it's not a very convincing Australian accent and, while I've been there on holiday, the cracks in my very limited knowledge are starting to show. However, I'm often referred to as "the Australian guy" by my coworkers.

I don't want to give this job up, but I don't really know how to get out of this hole I've dug for myself. I've tried to gradually change my accent to my normal one, but it hasn't really worked. Should I just talk normally from Monday and see what happens? It seems too shocking and open for humiliation, plus I'm worried my superiors might not appreciate the year-long charade.

Comment: I think you're april foolin' us, but this is funny nonetheless.

Comment: You could always try to slowly wean off it and make it seem like you're _learning_ how to speak without the accent

Comment: Slowly change it to a New Zealand accent with Scottish overtones.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a joke.  Not a question

Comment: OK but leave it up for the duration of April Fool's Day.

Comment: See also joke with punchline "I wathn't making fun of you, I wath making fun of him!"

Answer (score 9):

Your course is clear, you have only one path open to you. You must resign your current position and emigrate to Australia.

I recommend Tallangatta, VIC. No one will track you down there. Also it is the setting for a [major classic movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CJHRqZwYuc).

Comment: Terrible idea, possibly the worst country I ever visited, spent 4 hours at the airport with armed police threatening to lock me up before I got through on my one week visa. Probably the crucifix I was wearing. Incredibly rude people over there.

Comment: Well then Xophmeister certainly picked the bally wrong accent to go gammin about with dint he.

Comment: He did indeed by golly by gum, yer not wrong cobber.

Comment: @Kilisi I am Australian and I think you are generalising an entire population of 25 odd million with that statement.  I'm sorry you had a bad experience here, but  I very much doubt that wearing Christian ornaments would have been negatively received in what is ostensibly a Christian country.

Comment: @JaneS well, I blamed the crucifix, because otherwise I can only assume rascism.... unless everyone is treated like that... even my wife got badly treated... I'm over it anyway

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't so much the *presence* of a crucifix as the *absence* of little corks dangling from your hat.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst this is a bit of a tricky situation to get yourself out of, there are a couple of things you can do. You do need to come clean though because it could give you a very bad reputation as someone who isn't trust worthy and can't be taken seriously. Here are some things you can do though:

- ***A*** lways be honest
- ***P*** repare for the questioning
- ***R*** eason with your co-workers
- ***I*** nstall confidence in people again
- ***L*** Laugh it off with your co-workers
- ***F*** orget that it happened
- ***O*** wn up to it
- ***O*** ffer to make amends
- ***L*** earn from your mistake
- ***S*** et sail to Australia, there's no getting out of this one

Oh and next time; do an Irish accent. It's so much easier.

Comment: I see what you did there

Comment: @newguy You don't say?

Answer (score 2):

Tell your coworkers one day that you've been practicing a [nation] accent because you feel like it would be professionally useful in [nation], that you've been a bit shy to mention it because you were embarrassed, and that now you'd like to see what they think of it.

Then talk naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Dude simple solution - just speak your own language and tell them that you're learning something new and you will practice that now onwards. Chill